# audio_common for ROS2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
is there any audio_common equivalent package for ROS2?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
G.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354035/audio_common-for-ros2/) by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2022-02-02**:
I have the same question and am not sure whether the project linked in the accepted answer actually addresses this. Hence, I opened a question on the github of github_common: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build that now.

The ROS topic bridges aren't working yet, but it'll happily stream audio from a robot's sound card to a remote machine or play canned audio

https://github.com/BrettRD/ros-gst-bridge

Audio-common was too limited for my application, I've used image messages for audio with a custom encoding string in the past, but I'm about to define some new messages. I'd be glad to have some input.

---

Originally posted by [BrettRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/55733/brettrd/) with karma: 86 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2022-02-02**:
Hi BrettRD, thanks for starting and sharing such an ambitious project! My use-case is closer to the original audio_common: Play one from a set of audio files located on disk through ROS commands. Do you have a tutorial or instructions on how to do this with your project? I failed to find this on the linked github page. Cheers!

**Comment by [BrettRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/55733/brettrd/) on 2022-02-02**:
I don't have many examples of using ROS for audio. I have some improvements penciled in for this year though, that includes more docs.

Off the top of my head, A pipeline like this should do something, (something might include eating all of your network bandwidth with raw audio):

Machine with the mic:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-plugin-path=install/gst_bridge/lib/gst_bridge/ alsasrc ! audioconvert ! rosaudiosink ros-name="mic_node" ros-topic="very_noise"
```

Machine with the speakers:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-plugin-path=install/gst_bridge/lib/gst_bridge/ rosaudiosrc ros-name="spk_node" ros-topic="very_noise"  ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false
```

If you have a burning need for compressed audio *in ROS*, I'd love to field a pull request (even one that doesn't yet work) for a ROS message wrapper and bridge nodes that handle raw GST buffers.

`rosrawsink` and `rosrawsrc` are on my wish-list.

At the moment, I use GStreamer's UDP elements to move H264 video, not ROS topics.